# How to unmarshal this type of xml in java

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, dtd

I am new to Rest API. I have a xml output which i need to unmarshal. Below is the xml output:

```
<dsml>
    <entries>
        <entry dn="uid=7686,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
            <att name="uid">
                <value>7568766</value>
            </att>
            <att name="email">
                <value>new@gmail.com</value>
            </att>
            <att name="callname">
                <value>John</value>
            </att>
        </entry>
        <entry dn="uid=7689,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
            <att name="uid">
                <value>7678766</value>
            </att>
            <att name="callname">
                <value>Mike</value>
            </att>
        </entry>
        <entry dn="uid=7690,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
            <att name="uid">
                <value>75858766</value>
            </att>
            <att name="email">
                <value>old@gmail.com</value>
            </att>
            <att name="callname">
                <value>rahul</value>
            </att>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</dsml>
```

The actual xml output has total 37 entries. Below is the model class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "uid")
    private int uid;

    @XmlElement(name = "callname")
    private String callname;

    @XmlElement(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return uid;
    }
    public void setId(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return callname;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String callname) {
        this.callname = callname;
    }
    public String getmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Below is the Rest Api class code:

```
public class UsingRestAPI {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("www.example.com");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) 
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
            String apioutput="",temp="";
            while ((apioutput = br.readLine()) != null) {
                temp += apioutput;
                System.out.println(apioutput);
            }


            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            User user = (User) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(temp));

            System.out.println(user.getId());
            System.out.println(user.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(user.getmail());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While executing this code, i am getting error

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 110; External DTD: Failed to read external DTD 'dsml.dtd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property.]

I have tried by changing the propert ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD to true, but it gave another error:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD value: true
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at UsingRestAPI.main(UsingRestAPI.java:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

**(edited answer: UserClass and DsmlFactory getEntities() method edited)**

I think it's because of difference of your Xml structure and your Class-structure. I would never use elements having same name but different value types (like your `att` and `value` elements). Why? It's not a problem for the Marshaller, it's a problem for the Unmarshaller. Because, as I know, it cannot define the type of a child element value, based on parent's `name` attribute. Even if you define static inner classes of generic type (e.g. `interface Attribute<V>` and `static class Uid<Integer>`, `static class Email<String>` and whatever, you will make your work only more complicated.

But if you wrote `@XmlElement(name="att") Set<Attribute> attributes`, where the attribute count is not important for the Marshaller, and the Unmarshaller as well, it is something else.

However to keep it simple, I would really recommend the structure `<email>{value}</email>`, `<uid>{value}</uid>`, etc.

I've made a simple Xml Marshaller/Unmarshaller to test (without REST), this works:

My `Dslm` Xml root class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dsml {

    @XmlElement
    private Entities entities;

    public Dsml() {}
    public Dsml(Entities entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public Entities getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void print() {
        entities.print();
    }
}
```

---

My `Entities` class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entities {
    @XmlElement(name = "entity")
    private Set<User> users = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Entities() {}

    public Entities(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(users);
    }

    public void print() {
        if (users != null && !users.isEmpty()) {
            users.stream().forEach(User::print);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No entities found");
        }
    }
}
```

---

My `User` class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String dn;

    @XmlElement
    private int uid;

    @XmlElement
    private String email;

    @XmlElement
    private String callname;


    public User() {}

    public User(int uid, String dn, String email, String callname) {
        setUid(uid);
        setEmail(email);
        setCallname(callname);
        setDn(dn);
    }

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCallname() {
        return callname;
    }

    public void setCallname(String callname) {
        this.callname = callname;
    }

    public String getDn() {
        return dn;
    }

    public void setDn(String dn) {
        this.dn = dn;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Dn: " + dn);
        System.out.println("Uid: " + uid);
        System.out.println("Email: " + email);
        System.out.println("Callname: " + callname);
    }
}
```

---

My `DsmlFactory` Marshaller/Unmarshaller test-class (be sure you have `D:\` partition and you have Read|ReadWrite rights on it or type any other path within methods `saveXml()` and `readAndPrint()`:

```
public final class DsmlFactory {
    private DsmlFactory() {}
    public static Entities getEntities() {
        Set<User> users = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        users.add(new User(1000, "dn1", "email1", "callname1"));
        users.add(new User(2000, "dn2", "email2", "callname2"));
        users.add(new User(3000, "dn3", "email3", "callname3"));
        users.add(new User(4000, "dn4", "email4", "callname4"));
        users.add(new User(5000, "dn5", "email5", "callname5"));
        return new Entities(users);
    }

    public static void saveXmlTest() {
        try {
            File file = new File("D:/test.xml");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Dsml.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            Dsml dsml = new Dsml(getEntities());
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(dsml, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(dsml, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void readAndPrintXml() {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Dsml.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            Dsml dsml = (Dsml) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new File("D:/test.xml") );
            dsml.print();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void testIt() {
        saveXmlTest();
        readAndPrintXml();
    }
}
```

---

And my `main` TestDrive:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DsmlFactory.testIt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why donot you Save the Xml in a file and then pass it into unmarshal

New Version_:

```
User user = (User) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("c:/temp/user.xml") );//File path
```

it will not give any errors.

visit-: http://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to try the following:

Step 1: Create a class named `Attribute` as follows:

Attribute.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Attribute implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;
private String value;
public Attribute() {
 }
public Attribute(String name, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
 }
@XmlAttribute
public String getName() {
    return name;
 }
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }
@XmlElement
public String getValue() {
    return value;
 }
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
 }
}
```

Step 2: Please modify your class named `Student` as follows:

Student.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Student implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Attribute> attributes;
private String distinguishedName;
public Student() {
 }
public Student(String distinguishedName, List<Attribute> attributes) {
    this.distinguishedName = distinguishedName;
    this.attributes = attributes;
 }
@XmlAttribute(name = "dn")
public String getDistinguishedName() {
    return distinguishedName;
 }
public void setDistinguishedName(String distinguishedName) {
    this.distinguishedName = distinguishedName;
 }
@XmlElement(name = "att", type = Attribute.class)
public List<Attribute> getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
 }
public void setAttributes(List<Attribute> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
 }

}
```

Step 3: Please create a class named `DSML` as follows:

DSML.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "dsml")
public class DSML implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Student> entries;

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "entries")
@XmlElement(name = "entry", type = Student.class)
public List<Student> getEntries() {
    return entries;
 }
public void setEntries(List<Student> entries) {
    this.entries = entries;
 }
}
```

Step 4: Now its time to convert XML to Java object as follows:

UsingRestAPI.java

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DSML.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
DSML dsml = (DSML) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(temp));
```